# How to remove Entitlement after refund a test order (in app purchase) in play console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Am testing in-app purchase in my app, i made a test order then while refund it I forgot to check on remove Entitlement box, now am stuck with this in-app purchase

I contact play console support in 11 Aug and they always reply ("we are investigating the issue")

How to remove the Entitlement ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a solution, from your app: **consume** the product.

Add this temporary code and run it for your purchase.

```
private fun testConsumePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
    val params = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
        .build()
    billingClient.consumeAsync(params) { _, _ ->
        Timber.w("Consumed!")
    }
}
```

After this, remove the code and continue testing as usual. You will not own the SKU anymore and you will be unblocked, you can buy it again on your main test account. Remember next time to check the "Remove Entitlement" box with your refund :-)

Comment: but this purchase in non-consumable (one-time purchase)

Comment: Actually, the in-app purchase does not have a consumable attribute defined. It's up to you how you use it. For example my in-app purchase was also non-consumable. However I decided to consume it once to unblock myself. Then I never used that code again.

Comment: yes it works, thanks

Comment: Yeah, consuming for debug purposes is fine and allows you to unlock the item for buying it again. But is it me being non-native or is this toggle is super misleading? If actually understood the contrary and let the checkbox unchecked assuming I couldn't buy again... Really confusing IMO. Thanks anyway for the heads-up @RumburaK :)

Comment: @Rumurak Thanks for this help. Copy, pasted, and worked like a charm

Comment: 2 years later and still works as intended! It's a shame Google Play console doesn't streamline this process for us..

Comment: Thank you so much! Very important info - you've helped me

Answer (score 4):

I Contacted Play console support, the respond is it will be added in the future

So as a question answer is: NO you can't remove entitlement after refunding

> The Play Console doesn’t currently support removing entitlement when a
> refund has already been issued. Luckily, we place a high value on
> developer feedback, and I’ll be sure to pass along your specific
> feedback to our product team. We’re continually adding new features
> and functionality, so please stay tuned.

Comment: I can confirm that consumeAsync remove entitlement after refund. So Google (and yours?) statement is not correct.

Comment: correct or not, it's their statement sent by mail to me and I don't know why I should provide this info to you, in the context of the answer it's not a handy way with the test purchase. Moreover, I don't see the purpose of your comment.

Comment: My comment was to make it clear that you *can* clear a non-consumable where you have messed up and forgot to trigger "Remove entitlement" before you refund. This saves you time and continue testing will work. It also ensure that users who got refunds w/o this ticketed don't keep a function they no longer payed for.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Google's test playground from the API docs:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/consume

Just fill in your token, appId and productId and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter you can use

```
import 'package:in_app_purchase_android/billing_client_wrappers.dart';

BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient((wr){});
billingClient.consumeAsync('the_long_purchase_token');
```

Purchase token you can get in billingClient.queryPurchaseHistory or in your Google Play dev console - Order Management - Order Details - Copy Purchase Token.

Comment: Thank you very much Ilya K ! That was a nice trick to make a non-consumable that was refunded (without entitlement) be removed from playstore.

Comment: You are an absolute star @Ilya K , this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

After a refund, you should be able to make another purchase. Just clear your app data, and purchase again.

Comment: I tried that and the billing client says that I own this item and can't purchase it again

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem, when I went to refund a test product but forgot to check 'Remove Entitlement.'

What I did as a workaround was simply made a new product / product ID within Google Play, and then disabled the old one. This allowed me to make the test purchase again, but this time I made sure to check 'Remove Entitlement' before pressing the Refund button.

It's silly Google Play doesn't allow us to remove entitlement *after* issuing a refund. Especially since entitlement removal it's opt-in. Hopefully in the future...

Comment: I think Disabling product ID is good for unpublished products only